# Why does CreateNoWindow affect core utilization?

Tags: c#, createprocess, azure-batch, numa

I am trying to get 100% utilization from an HBv2 VM in Azure Batch. I have a test program, Framework 4.7.2 C#, that gets the number of processors and creates that number of copies of itself that create prime numbers for 30 seconds. I have added the following to app.config

```
    <runtime>
        <Thread_UseAllCpuGroups enabled="true"/>
        <GCCpuGroup enabled="true"/>
        <gcServer enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
```

and now Environment.ProcessorCount returns 120, but creating the child processes using

```
    new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = processFileName,
        Arguments = i.ToString(),
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };
```

results in about 70% utilization. The Task Manager shows utilization of the NUMA nodes
at 100% for two and about 50% for the other two.

If the processes are created with CreateNoWindow set to false, then I get 100% utilization.

Does anyone know why the CreateNoWindow flags makes any difference?

Comment: Remove any Console.WriteLine() calls from the code and try again.

Comment: There was a Console.WriteLine, but removing it did not affect the results.

Comment: On retesting, the changes made no difference.